# how to use multiple generator in keras fit_generator()

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I want to train the multi-input model on a set of images. I use `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` and `fit_generator` in keras.

The problem is I don't know how to use multiple generators.

This is my inputs & output generator and seeds are same:

```
input1 = imageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(directory=base_data_directory + 'img/' + mode+'/', **img_generator_config)
input2 = imageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(directory=base_data_directory + 'edge/' + mode,**edge_generator_config)
output = imageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(directory=base_data_directory + 'label/' + mode, **label_generator_config)
```

How should I use `fit_generator` with this data?

Comment: The answer is provided here in StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205451/joining-two-directoryiterators-in-keras)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should build the custom data generator or just use the fit function of Keras and make your input data as follows:

```
x = [[image1, feature1], [image2, feature1], [image3, feature1]]

y = [class1, class2, class1]
```